# I have changed my project name after installing the pod file , Unexpectedly am facing the following issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

```
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
```

> error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod
>   install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Answer (score 3):

remove the workspace file and run pod install again:

rm -rf MyProject.xcworkspace
pod install

Comment: i have done again and again , but i could not resolve my issue

Comment: try by Deleting Podfile.lock , Pods folder and workspase  and clean and pod.install and clean,
make sure you are opening workspace.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to complete change you project name without any error than Create new project and copy all the files in old projects to new project. If you change your pod files code than copy these files in your project after installing pod in new project .Thanks 
 `(First backup your old project)`

If you want to change only Application name than change only product name. Not Whole Directory name.